# Calling SProcs from EF best practice

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have imported some stored procedures in to EF.

Only stored procedures will be used, no LINQ to Entities.

What are best practices for this?

I simply have a class that uses an `Entities` field to call the stored procedures:

```
public class DataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    private readonly MyEntities entities = new MyEntities();

    public IEnumerable<MyObj> GetMyObJects()
    {
        return entities.GETMyObj().Select(x => new MyObj { Name = x.NAME }).ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyObj2> GetMyObJects2()
    {
        return entities.GETMyObj2().Select(x => new MyObj2 { Name = x.NAME }).ToList();
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyObj3> GetMyObJects3()
    {
        return entities.GETMyObj3().Select(x => new MyObj3 { Name = x.NAME }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Is this recommended? Should I be using a new `Entities` for every method?

As below:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObj3> GetMyObJects3()
{            
    using(MyEntities entities = new MyEntities())
    {
        return entities.GETMyObj3().Select(x => new MyObj3 { Name = x.NAME }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe best practice is to wrap your context in a using so it's disposed of as quickly as possible, but depending on the lifetime of your DataAccess class the difference could be negligible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. what you have in your post is the recommended way, so you would have something like:

```
public IEnumerable<MyObj3> GetMyObJects3()
{            
    using(MyEntities entities = new MyEntities())
    {
        ObjectResult<SPResult> Results = entities.GetMyObJects3();
        IEnumerable<MyObj3> results = Results.ToList();

        return results;
    }
}
```

Using the EDMX file , create function imports. in this example `GetMyObJects3()` is the function import.

Comment: What are the advantages or disadvantages of using a `using` in this context? If I don't use a `using`, `entities` will be disposed when my `DataAccess` object is garbage collected?

Comment: Since it is only within this method, you should really use the `using` statement because it gives you the exception handling without any additional code, if you don't use it then you will have to manually Dispose it, which could leave your connection open in case of exception

Answer (score 1):

Julie Lerman has written a pretty comprehensive article with sample code on this topic, it's located [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As long as your code only reads data from the database I don't see any problem doing that.

Comment: Some SProcs write too. What's the problem with writes?